# "Object("Cube").pose" is "None". Why?

Tags: python, objects, bones

Ok, this is my first post here. So hi Blender Stack Exchange Community! I have a problem: I want to program an addon and need to get the informations of the bones. I found a post wich says me they would stay at `Object("Cube").pose.bones`. Now, if I try I get an error message wich says me that bones dosen't exist in None. After testing I saw that `Object("Cube").pose` was `None`. Here is my operator code:

```
import bpy
    
class Test_OT_Operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.cursor_center"
    bl_label = "Simple operator"
    bl_description = "Center 3d cursor"

    def execute(self, context):
  
        ob = bpy.context.object

        #print(ob.pose.bones[0].matrix) # Would rise an error, I commented this line
        print(ob) # this here works
        print(ob.pose) # this here is None
        bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_center()

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Now, after I saw yesterday that it worked without any errors. I correctly assigned the bones to my Cube, and I can bend the Cube with the bones. So, I really don't understand why, why it dosen't work now. I really hope you, more experimented Community, could help me to understand. I am really new with python and started coding Lua 2 years ago and Typescript 3 months, so I knew how to program (by the way, sorry if I have a bad english, I am trying to improve it, too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is strange… I just changed `print(ob.pose)` to `print(ob.parent.pose)` and it seems to works. Idk why or how, but it seems to work and I am just happy about. But still, thanks if someone actually tried to help me.

Comment: I will mark this as solved in 2 days. Wow, my first post was actually weird… If someone needs help I could try to help you.

Comment: objects have no pose. armatures have poses. ob.parent is the armature. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.pose